# Error in Layout Inflater in fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am creating an UI using fragments. In onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState), I am parsing the JSON data. I am getting the the following error:

> 07-17 15:23:18.089: W/System.err(1368):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.afghanread.android/com.afghanread.android.AfghanMagActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class fragment 07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:223)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   com.afghanread.android.AfghanMagActivity.onCreate(AfghanMagActivity.java:26)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   ... 11 more 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90) 07-17
>   15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:154) 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171) 07-17 15:23:18.129:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   com.afghanread.android.CategoryFragment.parseJSON(CategoryFragment.java:72)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   com.afghanread.android.CategoryFragment.onCreateView(CategoryFragment.java:161)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:713)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:905)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:983)
>   07-17 15:23:18.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1368):   at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4141)

My code is :

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

ArrayList<String> cat = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView list;
DatabaseManager manager;
static String DATABASE_NAME = "afghanread.sqlite";
static Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
TextView text;
TextView cat_name;
int length;
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
        "OS/2" };

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    parseJSON();
    manager = new DatabaseManager(null, DATABASE_NAME, null,
            DATABASE_VERSION);

}

private void parseJSON() {
    try {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(getJSONData());
        JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
        length = jArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            JSONObject tmpJson = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Category category = new Category();

            category.setCategotyId(tmpJson.getInt("category_id"));
            category.setCategoryName(tmpJson.getString("category_name"));

            // manager.insertCategoryDetails(category);

        }
        System.out.println("Jason parsing successful.......");
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getJSONData() {
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String line = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://183.182.84.197:88/Sayyed_fahim/mobile/category.php");
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            in = entity.getContent();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line);

            result = sb.toString();
            result = result.trim();
            result = result.substring(1, result.length());
            Log.i("RESULT", result);
        } else
            Log.e("Error", "" + statusCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }

            httpPost = null;
            httpClient = null;
            httpResponse = null;
            entity = null;
            in = null;
            reader = null;
            sb = null;
            line = null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    System.out.println("Inside the afghan Read category");
    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoryfragment, null);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_list);

    /*
     * ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new
     * ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
     * android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
     */
    parseJSON();
    list.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.categoryitem,
            values));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    String item = (String) values[arg2];
    LibraryFragment fragment = (LibraryFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.library);
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
        fragment.setText(item);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                LibraryActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", item);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String names[];
    Context mCtx;
    int item;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, int categoryitem, String[] values) {

        this.names = values;
        this.mCtx = ctx;
        this.item = categoryitem;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(item, null);
            cat_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);

        }

        cat_name.setText(names[position]);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

}

How to resolve the issue??

Comment: post R.layout.categoryfragment and  R.layout.categoryitem

Comment: initialize layout inflater in onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the web call fails and you are passing null to `new JSONObject(getJSONData())`.
Is JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(getJSONData()); line 72 as stated as origin for the nullpointer in your logcat output:  com.afghanread.android.CategoryFragment.parseJSON(CategoryFragment.java:72)?

Not totally related to the error but also a big problem in your code. You are doing a webcall inside the UI-Thread. This will freeze the phone until the json data is loaded from your server. You should at least put all the data loading code inside a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and update your UI in the onPostExecute method.